# How to transfer the localstorage data from one device to another in android(SQlite)

Tags: android, sqlite, local-storage, android-sqlite

I am developing an android application, in that am storing some data into localStorage using SQLite. Main thing is whatever data is stored in the LocalStorage I want to transfer that data into another device(Mobile to Mobile, Tab to Tab or Mobile to Tab) whenever I want. Is there anything to achieve this.

Comment: I am not sure but you have to code for wifi direct , socket prog, and bluetooth data transfer. you can execute these component with broadcast rec, intent filter

Comment: Give me some needful information(Code,article,architecture) will be helpful. I am totally null in this. @Akashkumar

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can but its suitable for small data-set.
you can pass data using intents.

**Communication between two Applications in Android using Messenger**

[**Here is Example.**](http://infobloggall.com/2015/04/14/communication-between-two-applications-in-android-using-messenger/)

[**Also have look here too.**](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-developers/6BTSWg1cZcg)

Comment: Not exactly, I want to send the localStorage data which is stored SQlite not mesaages nor communication between two application. @Sohailzahid

Comment: Then you should  a web server which best approach for sharing db data.

Answer (score 0):

I would save files to a public location where other apps can access them remotely using an external MySQL DB. JSON encode all your data.

See this link as well.

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesExternal